# Prevent CheckBox Checked event from firing

Tags: c#, wpf

I have some CheckBoxes created dynamically on code. I do read a barcode using a barcode reader. I'm trying to stop the Unchecked and Checked events from firing when I'm using the barcode. For that effect I:

1. only assign both events when I get the focus on the Checkboxes, and when I lose the focus I take the events out.
2. after each Checked and Unchecked event I assign the focus to another control in the window (so the LostFocus event gets triggered)

But went I use the barcode reader, all of the CheckBoxes objects receive the Unchecked event if they were checked (but not the Checked event if they were unchecked).

Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

The only places where the Unchecked method is being used are the ones in the code show, nowhere else in the code of the application.

A pointer to a better way to handle this dynamic creation of Checkboxes will not go unappreciated.

```cs
private void SomeMethod ()
{
  foreach (KeyValuePair<String, String> kvp in someDictionary)
  {
    CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();
    checkBox.Content = kvp.Key;
    checkBox.GotFocus +=new RoutedEventHandler(checkBox_GotFocus);
    checkBox.LostFocus += new RoutedEventHandler(checkBox_LostFocus);
    checkBox.ClickMode = ClickMode.Release;
    Grid.SetRow(checkBox, fileSelectionGrid.RowDefinitions.Count);
    fileSelectionGrid.Children.Add(checkBox);
    RowDefinition row = new RowDefinition();
    fileSelectionGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(row);
  }
}

void checkBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  CheckBox checkBox = sender as CheckBox;
  checkBox.Checked -= new RoutedEventHandler(checkBox_Checked);
  checkBox.Unchecked -= new RoutedEventHandler(checkBox_Unchecked);
}

void checkBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  CheckBox checkBox = sender as CheckBox;
  checkBox.Checked += new RoutedEventHandler(checkBox_Checked);
  checkBox.Unchecked += new RoutedEventHandler(checkBox_Unchecked);
}
```

**EDIT :**

Just checked that the click event is not raised when the CheckBox doesn't have the focus.

Comment: I don't see how an event that is not registered can get fired.   Does the bar code reader fire the checkBox_GotFocus event?

Comment: No, doesn't. I'm very perplexed as well.

Comment: When it does fire what is the sender?

Comment: Then it appears your bar code "reader" is somehow putting focus on the checkboxes and unchecking them.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be the case. The reader just sends a message, through a message center. The reader is not aware that the screen where the checkbox is does exist at all.
Furthermore, the checkboxes don't exist when the message handler for the screen is registered. They only get created after a specific message is received, which wasn't the message that I was receiving when the strange behaviour happened. I did check that the method that creates the checkboxes wasn't called twice (which it wasn't).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I added event handlers for KeyUp and KeyDown (the barcode input is consider keystrokes) to the control that was receiving the focus with:

```cs
e.Handled = true;
```

and that stopped the checkboxes receiving them.

As per the documentation, it is a Bubbling event. And the control and the checkboxes are cousins

- control->grid 1->parent grid
- checkbox->grid 2->parent grid

I would not have expected it to go up to the parent grid and then down. I need to read more about WPF.

Seems to me a bit  of a hack. If someone gets a better answer, I will mark it.

Answer (score 2):

Usually for such kind of problems i declare a bool flag which is assigned value before and after code line where an event will fire and when that event is fired the first thing it does is to check for that flag value.

For e.g.

```
bool flag = false;

private void SomeMethod()
{
  flag = true;
  YourCheckBox.checked = false;
  flag = false;
}

void YourCheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  if (flag)
     return;

  // Do something....
}

void YourCheckBox_UnChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  if (flag)
     return;

  // Do something....
}
```

When i assigned flag = true the next line will fire selection changed event. when i does it will return coz flag is set to true;

Comment: In my case, the value is not changed in the code. So there is no YourCheckBox.checked. It can only be done through the GUI.

Comment: In your sample you have events checkBox_Checked and checkBox_Unchecked.

Comment: Well, in fact, in his sample, should be:
YourCheckBox.IsChecked = false;

Answer (score 0):

Instead of basing on loosing focus, try disabling  your event handlers directly before barcode reading and enabling them afterward. Something like this:

```
public void ReadBarcode(ComboBox cmbx)
{
    FieldInfo info = cmbx.GetType().GetField("SelectedIndexChanged", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    if (info != null)
    {
       object obj = info.GetValue(cmbx);
       if (obj is EventHandler)
       {
          EventHandler handler = (EventHandler)obj;
          cmbx.SelectedIndexChanged -= handler;
          //              
          // Perform your bar code reading here.
          // 
          cmbx.SelectedIndexChanged += handler;
       }
    }
}
```

I have used a single combobox for clarity sake, obviously you can use the same technique for an array of comboboxes

Comment: The barcode reading happens in a different dll, and a message is passed through a messaging system.Found a solution/hack, that I will post once Slashdot allows me to.